# Are background color and border color supported for pdf forms?

Tags: color, pdf, latex3, viewers, forms

I'm playing a bit with the new `l3pdffield-testphase`.

```
\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase}
\DocumentMetadata{uncompress}
\documentclass[varwidth, margin = 5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{l3pdffield-testphase}
% For some reason, l3color is not in TeXLive, but l3draw defines color macros
\usepackage{l3draw} 

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN\pdffieldtextfield\pdffield_textfield:n
% Manual definition taken from xcolor-material
\color_set:nnn{MaterialOrange100}{HTML}{FFE0B2}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\pdffieldtextfield{V = {Test 1}, name = test1, backgroundcolor = MaterialOrange100, bordercolor = red, width = 4cm}

\end{document}
```

I understand that fillable forms rely heavily on the viewer (the `chrome/chromium` internal pdf viewer does a pretty good job, whereas `evince` segfaults). But neither chrome nor evince can display neither the `backgroudcolor` nor the `bordercolor`. So, my question is: is the error on the viewer side or is it something that I don't understand with the new `l3color` color management or is it buggy for now?

Comment: you would need `\pdfmanagement_add:nnn{Catalog/AcroForm}{NeedAppearances}{true}` to see the colors, but `NeedAppearances` is deprecated in pdf 2.0, so  normally it is better to define an specific appearance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to activate the `NeedAppearances` option to tell the pdfviewer that it should build up a "look". This can be done with

```
\pdfmanagement_add:nnn{Catalog/AcroForm}{NeedAppearances}{true}
```

But `NeedAppearances` is deprecated in pdf 2.0. The alternative is to add appearances (=small graphics) to the definition (l3draw is not required, you can also use tikz or whatever; in a current LaTeX it is no longer needed to load pdfmanagement-testphase explicitly, it is done by \DocumentMetadata):

```
\DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass[varwidth, margin = 5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{l3pdffield-testphase}
\usepackage{l3draw}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN\pdffieldtextfield\pdffield_textfield:n
\color_set:nnn{MaterialOrange100}{HTML}{FFE0B2}

\pdffield_appearance:nn{cjorssen/textfield}
 {
   \draw_begin:
    \color_fill:n { MaterialOrange100 }
    \color_stroke:n { red }
    \draw_path_rectangle:nn { 0 , 0 } { 4cm , 12pt }
    \draw_path_use:n {fill}
    \draw_path_use:n {stroke}
   \draw_end:
 }  

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\pdffieldtextfield{V = {Test 1}, name = test1, appearance=cjorssen/textfield, width = 4cm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect, Ulrike. Is it backward compatible? I mean with older pdf specs?

Comment: yes, appearances exist also in 1.7 and earlier, but do not expect every viewer to handle that identically. There is lots of history here ...

Comment: During the editing and once edited, the field has lost all its lovely appearance (in chrome/chromium, evince segfaults).