Fillable form output difference between adobe document cloud reader vs chrome pdfviewer
I am trying to produce a fillable form that can then be saved.  When I view the form with evince or the Chrome pdf viewer, everything looks fine.  When viewing through the adobe cloud-based viewer, none of the text fields or check boxes show up.
This is my minimum reproducible sample, test.tex
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\documentclass[
  10pt,
]{article}
\IfFileExists{bookmark.sty}{\usepackage{bookmark}}{\usepackage{hyperref}}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form} % End is right before end of document.
\TextField[width=3in]{Text field}

\TextField[value=test]{Default Field with pre-filled text}

\CheckBox[checked=true]{Checked box}

\CheckBox{Check} \CheckBox{boxes} \CheckBox{in} \CheckBox{a}
\CheckBox{single} \CheckBox{row}

\end{Form}  
\end{document}

Then run through:XeTeX 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993
xelatex test.tex
Viewed through Chrome pdf viewer:

Viewed through Adobe:

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Update - not just xelatex.  I tried with the basic latex command, which shows version: pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22

Welcome to TeX:SX! I would argue that this is a problem with the viewer. If I compile your code and open it with Acrobat Reader, the form fields and their contents are shown. Note that you should probably delete the line with \IfFileExists and just load the hyperref package.

the viewer probably doesn't create appearances on-the-fly, but I have no idea if there is an option to change that. As an alternative you could create field with appearances, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/685091/2388

Thank you.  The \IfFileExists was leftover from what pandoc added to the file, so I just left the line intact.  I was mostly wondering if anyone had seen this with the Adobe Cloud reader.  (It works fine on Acrobat Reader on my Windows machine.)  I can work around the issue, by opening the file with the browser's PDF viewer instead.

Just as a note: I did read that you referred to the Adobe Cloud reader (which I don't use, so I can't tell anything about this). I was only referring to Acrobat Reader, because this is the most reliable PDF viewer ist most cases. If the other PDF viewer is not showing things, it is therefore likely a problem with this viewer (and not a LaTeX issue).

In some viewers, you have to enable forms for a document before they show up, but I've no idea if this applies to the cloud viewer.

And today it works.  So I believe it was indeed a flaw in the viewer, and I'm guessing it was updated.  Thanks for the sanity checking!
